# Looping through array until value is found and then breaking

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo, dijit.form

I have a select field which on change I get the value. As I am looping through the select values I want to detect if it matches the value I have if it does I also want to check if the object contains a flag===true I wrote in. All I keep getting is the amount of items in the array and whatever the last one's flag is what the final value is.

```
array[
 object{
  value: fromSelectChange //if matches && flag is set to true stop looping
  flag: true
 }
]
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: The code block is to cryptic for me, where's the whole onchange function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My First reaction would be to throw it all into a for in loop. I usually find it one of the easier ways to see if something iterating on arrays will work.

```
var fromSelectChangeReturn;
for (index in array) {
    if (array[index].fromSelectChange == value && array[index].flag) {
        fromSelectChangeReturn = array[index].fromSelectChange;
        Break;
    }
}
```

For in MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

assuming array is you array

```
var array = [
  {value: fromSelectChange, flag: true},
  . . . // others
];
```

just use

```
function match(arr, value){
  var totalOk = 0;
  arr.every(function(el){
    if(el.flag && value == el.value){
      totalOk++;
    }
  });
  return totalOk;
}

alert(match(array))
```